# Is there another source to install papaja package?

Tags: r, github, installation, package, papaja

I'm trying to install `papaja` package on my windows machine. But I'm getting the following error message

```
Installing 3 packages: bookdown, rmdfiltr, zip
Installing packages into ‘C:/Users/cophuser/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error: Failed to install 'papaja' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.6:
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'
```

I used this command to install papaja

```
# Install devtools package if necessary
if(!"devtools" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) install.packages("devtools")

# Install the stable development verions from GitHub
devtools::install_github("crsh/papaja")

# Install the latest development snapshot from GitHub
devtools::install_github("crsh/papaja@devel")
```

Please let know what should I do if you know how to solve this issue

Comment: What is the command you used to install `papaja`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers I updated my question with the command I used to install `papaja`

Comment: Which of the three commands gives you the error?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I solved it by updating my Rtools to v.4.

Check here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/